# How to end up with a pointer to 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The program I'm working on crashes sometimes trying to read data at the address `0xCCCCCCCC`. Google (and StackOverflow) being my friends I saw that it's the MSVC debug code for uninitialized stack variable. To understand where the problem can come from, I tried to reproduce this behavior: problem is I haven't been able to do it.

Question is: have you a code snippet showing how a pointer can end pointing to `0xCCCCCCCC`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you initialized all your pointers to a known value?

Comment: @In silico +1, I'm not sure what the question here is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile your code with the [/GZ compiler switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hddybs7t%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [/RTCs switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Make sure that [/Od switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) is also used to disable any optimizations.

> s
>
> Enables stack frame run-time error checking, as follows:
>
> - Initialization of local variables to a nonzero value. This helps identify bugs that do not appear when running in debug mode. There is a greater chance that stack variables will still be zero in a debug build compared to a release build because of compiler optimizations of stack variables in a release build. Once a program has used an area of its stack, it is never reset to 0 by the compiler. Therefore, subsequent, uninitialized stack variables that happen to use the same stack area can return values left over from the prior use of this stack memory.
> - Detection of overruns and underruns of local variables such as arrays. /RTCs will not detect overruns when accessing memory that results from compiler padding within a structure. Padding could occur by using align (C++), /Zp (Struct Member Alignment), or pack, or if you order structure elements in such a way as to require the compiler to add padding.
> - Stack pointer verification, which detects stack pointer corruption. Stack pointer corruption can be caused by a calling convention mismatch. For example, using a function pointer, you call a function in a DLL that is exported as __stdcall but you declare the pointer to the function as __cdecl.

Answer (score 12):

```
int main()
{
    int* p;
}
```

If you build with the Visual C++ debug runtime, put a breakpoint in `main()`, and run, you will see that `p` has a value of `0xcccccccc`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but no, I just have some uninitialized random value.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have MSVC, but this code should produce the problem and compile with no warnings.

In file f1.c:

```
void ignore(int **p) { }
```

In file f2.c:

```
void ignore(int **p);
int main(int c, char **v)
{
  int *a;
  ignore(&a);
  return *a;
}
```

The call to `ignore` makes it look like `a` might be initialized. I doubt the compiler will warn in this case, because of the risk that the warning might be a false positive.

Comment: In both Visual C++ 2008 and 2010 this exact code generates level 1 warning C4700:  "uninitialized local variable 'a' used."  You would need to have `ignore` take a pointer or reference to `int*` in order for there to be any chance that `a` is initialized by the call to `ignore`.

Comment: Can you explain the risk of a false positive?

Comment: No warning and no 0xCC... addres on my computer. Is there special compilation options to enable the feature?

Comment: @James McNellis @Tomas Thanks for pointing this out. I meant of course `ignore (&a);` so that it looks like `ignore()` might initialize `a`.

Comment: @gregseth Well, writing `0xCCCCCCCC` all over the stack is expensive, so that may only be enabled by MSVC for debug builds. I have to admit that I do not know more than what is in your question.

Comment: @gregseth I have changed the assignment into a `return`. The compiler might optimize an assignment away (optimizations that remove undefined behaviors are allowed, because undefined behavior can be anything, even working normally).

Comment: @gregseth:  Visual C++ has a lot of settings for warnings.  You'll find them (in VS2008 anyway) under the General and Advanced subtabs of the C/C++ tab of the Property Pages dialog.  If somebody else set the project up, there's no telling what they are.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Ignore the warning that VC throws while running.

```
struct A{
    int *p;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    cout << (void *)a.p;
}
```