# Why would accessing this local member variable cause an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, members

I am trying to write a program that will read the contents of a .csv file into an array then print the results to the screen (part of a larger project) when the function `getNumberOfRooms()` is called an exception is thrown when it tries to return the value of the `numberOfRooms` variable, a private member within the class. Has anyone had a problem like this before or helped someone with this sort of problem? If so how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Full source code available here: https://bitbucket.org/skutov/micropuzzle/

The exception that is thrown when getNumberOfRooms() is called:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01354aa6 in MICROPUZZLE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
reading location 0xccccccd0.
```

These are the functions in question (all of the time the variable is referenced in the class)

```
ClassMap::ClassMap ()
{
    numberOfRooms = 0;

    // Get number of rooms in map.csv

    /* Find number of entries in map.csv file */

        numberOfRooms = number_of_lines;

    // allocate memory for rooms array

    /* loading data from file into array */
    }
}    

// self explanitory
int ClassMap::getNumberOfRooms()
{
    // Exception occurs on this line when accessing the variable
    return numberOfRooms;
}

int ClassMap::printRoomDescriptions ()
{
    for(int j = this->getNumberOfRooms(); j > 0; j--)
    {
        cout << roomArray[j].getDescription();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class header:

```
class ClassMap
{
private:
    int currentLocation;
    int numberOfRooms;
    // pointer to array initialised in constructor
    ClassRoom *roomArray;

public:
    // Constructors and Destructors
    ClassMap();
    ~ClassMap();

    // Print description, events and directions for current room
    std::string getCurrentRoom();

    // Change currentLocation to neighbour of current room if possible
    int moveRoom(char direction);


    // self explanitory
    int getNumberOfRooms();

    // dump room descriptions to command line (debugging)
    int printRoomDescriptions();

};
```

Here is the constructor for ClassMap which also initializes roomArray:

```
ClassMap::ClassMap ()
{
    numberOfRooms = 0;

    // Get number of rooms in map.csv

        unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
        FILE *infile = fopen("map.csv", "r");
        int ch;

        while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
            if ('\n' == ch)
                ++number_of_lines;
        fclose(infile);
        numberOfRooms = number_of_lines;




    // allocate memory for rooms array
    roomArray = new ClassRoom[numberOfRooms+1];

    // set starting room
    int currentLocation = 1;

    // load that shit up
    {
        // Holders for values read from file
        int newRoomID = 0;
        char newRoomDescription[79] = "";
        int newRoomNorthNeighbour = 0;
        int newRoomEastNeighbour = 0;
        int newRoomSouthNeighbour = 0;
        int newRoomWestNeighbour = 0;

        // used for iterations
        int i = 0;

        // File stream for map.csv
        std::ifstream mapFile;

        // Crack that shit open
        mapFile.open ("map.csv");

        // Line buffer for parsing
        std::string line;


        // For each line in the map.csv file read in the values into variables declared above then run initialise function for each room to store values into array
        while (std::getline(mapFile, line))
        {
            // re-init parameters

            newRoomID = 0;
            newRoomNorthNeighbour = 0;
            newRoomEastNeighbour = 0;
            newRoomSouthNeighbour = 0;
            newRoomWestNeighbour = 0;
            for(i = 0;i<79;i++)
            {
                newRoomDescription[i] = ' ';
            }


            int parameter = 0;

            int paraStart = 0;
            int paraEnd = 0;

            std::string buffer;
            std::istringstream iss(line);

            for(parameter = 0; parameter <= 5; parameter++)
            {
                // Empty buffer from last iteration
                buffer.clear();

                // Find end of current parameter
                paraEnd = line.find(',',paraStart+1);

                switch (parameter)
                {
                case 0:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart),(paraEnd-paraStart));
                    newRoomID = atoi(buffer.c_str());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart+2),(line.find("\"",paraStart+2)-(paraStart+2)));
                    for(i = 0;i<(buffer.length());i++)
                    {
                        newRoomDescription[i] = buffer.c_str()[i];
                    }
                    //newRoomDescription
                    break;
                case 2:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart+1),(paraEnd-paraStart));
                    newRoomNorthNeighbour = atoi(buffer.c_str());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart+1),(paraEnd-paraStart));
                    newRoomEastNeighbour = atoi(buffer.c_str());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart+1),(paraEnd-paraStart));
                    newRoomSouthNeighbour = atoi(buffer.c_str());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    buffer = line.substr((paraStart+1),(paraEnd-paraStart));
                    newRoomWestNeighbour = atoi(buffer.c_str());
                    break;
                } // switch

                // Cycle paraEnd to paraStart
                paraStart = paraEnd;

            } // for parameters loop

            // Init next room with data
            new (&roomArray[newRoomID]) ClassRoom(  newRoomNorthNeighbour,
                newRoomEastNeighbour,
                newRoomSouthNeighbour,
                newRoomWestNeighbour,
                newRoomDescription);

        } // while !EOF
        // Close the file because we're a good little program and we don't need that shit no more
        mapFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probbaly because the `this` pointer is invalid. Please show the code where you call `getNumberOfRooms()`. The problem is most likely there.

Comment: how do you initialize roomArray? could you show your constructor?

Comment: Added the full constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this issue is:

```
Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0
```

`0xcccccccc` is a special value used in debug mode to denote an unitialised pointer. (See [How to end up with a pointer to 0xCCCCCCCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618572/how-to-end-up-with-a-pointer-to-0xcccccccc) ) It is set in debug mode to **cause** this kind of crash - it means the pointer you are using is not yet setup. Once you set up the pointer correctly the error will go away. (The slight difference from `0xcccccccc` is the offset of the member you're trying to access inside that object.)

ADDED:

This is your error:

```
ClassRoom* roomArray = static_cast<ClassRoom*>( ::operator new ( sizeof ClassRoom * numberOfRooms ) );
```

This creates a local `roomArray` variable, and hides the member variable. What you really want is:

```
roomArray = static_cast<ClassRoom*>( ::operator new ( sizeof ClassRoom * numberOfRooms ) );
```

Or better yet:

```
roomArray = new ClassRoom[numberOfRooms];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, having taken your changes into account it hasn't made a difference to the program, except for making it look a bit neater. I've edited the changes into the original question. Just to make sure things are clear, the variable <code>numberOfRooms</code> is used fine in this context, it is the get function that causes the error.

Comment: The code does look better, but its still litttered with oddities, and potential errors. (Can't tell if they're actuall errors as we dont have all the code.) I think you really need to create a better reduced example of your code to show us if you want further help. See http://www.sscce.org/ for what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is your for loop `for(int j = this->getNumberOfRooms(); j > 0; j--)`. It should look like this: `for(int j = this->getNumberOfRooms()-1; j >= 0; j--)`.
The last accessible index in an arry with N entries is N-1. On the other hand, the first index is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, not quite where the problem lies but that did highlight another issue with the way I have written my .csv files. Saved a potential headache there.